# ReactJS: Redux state is not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm just starting with React and Redux and stumbled upon something I can't figure out by myself - I *think* that Redux state is not changing and it's causing (some of) errors. I'm checking state with use of remote-redux-devtools@0.5.0.
My code:

Categories.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getCategories } from '../../actions/categories';

export class Categories extends Component {
    static propTypes  = {
        categories: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getCategories();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Placeholder for categories.
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    categories: state.categories.categories
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCategories })(Categories);
```

../../actions/categories.js:

```
import axios from "axios";

import { CATEGORIES_GET } from "./types";

export const getCategories = () => dispatch => {
  return axios
    .get("/api/notes/categories/")
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: CATEGORIES_GET,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

reducers/categories.js:

```
import { CATEGORIES_GET } from '../actions/types.js';

const initialState = {
    categories: []
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CATEGORIES_GET:
            return {
                ...state,
                categories: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

store.js:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'remote-redux-devtools';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)));

export default store;
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import categories from './categories';

export default combineReducers({
    categories,
```

});

Using remote-redux-devtools, I've never seen anything in my state. Currently this code above gives me 3 errors, two of them being

> this.props.getCategories is not a function

My guess is that because there is some issue with `Categories` class, it's not passing anything to state and it could be root cause of errors. I had one more error, connected to `Categories` not being called with attributes, but for debug purposes I put empty array there - one error dissapeared, but that's it. I've also tried adding constructor to `Categories` and called `super()`, but did not help also.

Comment: could you share your `rootReducer` file?

Comment: Sure, added it at the end (reducers/index.js).

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue is that you're exporting your `Categories` class twice, once connected, the other not.

If you remove **export** from `export class Categories extends Component`, does it work as expected?

Comment: If i remove export, it prints ``"export 'Categories' was not found in './Categories'`` in npm server

Comment: You'll need to import it differently since it's actually using a `default`.

You would 

`import Categories from "./Categories"` instead of `import { Categories } from "./Categories"`

Comment: Yes, you're right and it solves majority of issues I had - no more ``this.props.getCategories is not a function`` and now I can display ``this.props.categories`` content by looping (If I can call it that) in Categories.js, but there is still one last thing - Redux state is still empty. My guess is that I configured it inproperly, since everything else works just fine.

Comment: Can you confirm that the API you're hitting is actually giving you the response you expect? You can just console.log the `res` in `getCategories`. to double check.

Comment: Yes, I'm retrieving from api what is expected - I printed it one of the components and was able to compare.

Answer (score 0):

When you're mapping the state in a component, you must access the desired variable through a reducer.

So instead of:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    categories: state.categories
});
```

You must use:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    categories: state.categories.categories
});
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, it should be done as you say. Changed this line, but unfortunately, no luck. It does not enter``CATEGORIES_GET`` in reducer (checked it with logging to console).

Answer (score 0):

Your props don't have getCategories method, because you didn't pass it as a function to `connect`.

A better approach is to define only the action code in your actions file and then use `mapDispatchToProps`.

../../actions/categories.js

```js
import axios from "axios";

export const getCategories = () => {
  axios
    .get("/api/notes/categories/")
    .then(res => res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Categories.js

```js
import { getCategories } from '../../actions/categories'
import { CATEGORIES_GET } from "./types";

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
     getCategories: () => dispatch(() => { type: CATEGORIES_GET, payload: getCategories() }),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Categories);
```